# Finding answers to system of equations

Tags: systems-of-equations, parametric

Let's say we have such a system structure of equations:

```
a(1,1)x(1) +a(2,1)x(2)....+a(n,1)x(n)=b(1)
a(1,2)x(1) +a(1,2)x(2)....+a(n,2)x(n)=b(2)
.
.
.
a(1,m)x(1) + a(2,m)x(2)...+a(n,m)x(n)=b(m)
where n,m are positive integers and A[1->n,1->m],B[1->m] are params.
```

Is there a fast way to determinate the unknown array X[1->n] ?

Comment: Do you know Gauss' elimination? It's a very basic tool used to solve linear systems.

Comment: I don't believe I have studied it yet ,but I will google it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is a system of linear equations. You can solve this by solving the matrix equation
$$\mathbf{Ax} = \mathbf{b}, $$

where $\mathbf{A}$ is an $n\times m$ matrix (or array), and $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ are vectors.

Depending on the structure of $\mathbf{A}$ you may solve this efficiently using particular factorization methods such as LU, LDL, or Cholesky-factorization. In general you could just use Gaussian Elimination.

Comment: I will google it. I still haven't learned about matrixes tho.

Comment: @TitiKokov OK, I will see if I can add something to make it a little clearer. However, you should definitely learn about linear algebra (where you also will learn about gaussian elimination), because here you will learn exactly about this. Are you programming or do you wish to solve it by hand?

Comment: Thank you. I will google it to see if I can understand it.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to point out that your setup is incorrect, per standard practice. That is, you have listed:
$$
a(1,1)x(1) +a(2,1)x(2)....+a(n,1)x(n)=b(1)\\
a(1,2)x(1) +a(1,2)x(2)....+a(n,2)x(n)=b(2)\\
.\\
.\\
.\\
a(1,m)x(1) + a(2,m)x(2)...+a(n,m)x(n)=b(m)\\
$$

In every implementation of a matrix I've seen, though, the ordering is (ROW,COL). This means that your matrix *should* be setup where the first coefficient in the first equation is $a(1,1)$, the second would be $a(1,2)$, etc.

You're going to get the wrong answer if you try to take your $A$ matrix and solve it because you don't have it configured correctly. Granted, if you're doing this by hand, it probably won't be an issue because you'll just write the numbers in the correct spot, but if you try to take your $A$ matrix and pass it through an algorithm you are bound for disappointment.

What you have written is $A^T x = b$, where the superscript $^T$ denotes the transpose operator.

Lastly, I'd like to point out that in your setup you declare matrix $A$ to be an $n\times m$-sized matrix (but again, this is misleading as well because you have $m$ *rows* and $n$ *columns*, so it is actually an $m\times n$-sized matrix). If the number of rows of $A$ is less than the number of columns you can't find an answer; you have fewer equations than unknowns and will be left having to state the value of (number of columns - number of rows) variables as the remaining variables will all be dependent on those values.

Comment: As far as I understand you want to point out the matrix is inversed (COL,ROW) . However in my question I ask a way to reslove this system of equesions I point nowhere [A] is a matrix. I point out it's a 2-dim 'param' set of numbers.The answer suggest I should use matrixes not the question itself.

Comment: Whether you meant it or not, the way that you've structured the question gives $a$ as a matrix of coefficients, $x$ as a vector of independent variables, and $b$ as a vector of outputs.

As in the other answer, the most basic way you would solve this is with the Gaussian eliminitaion; read more on "reduced row echelon form". 

If you have (as you do) a matrix equation of the form
$$
Ax = B
$$
You can solve for 'x' by inverting matrix a:
$$
x = A^{-1}B
$$
But again, this only works if A can be inverted, which implies it is square. If you can't invert A then there is no unique solution for x.

Comment: [Here's](https://www.math.hmc.edu/calculus/tutorials/linearsystems/) a good tutorial on Gaussian elimination and reduced row echelon form: